# Silverlight Dispose pattern with WCF (Async)

Tags: wcf, silverlight, dispose, channel, stateful

I'm a little new to Silverlight, and I want to know how to deal with the Faulted/Disposing of a WCF service.

I'm used to something like this ([wcf abort/close pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/197531/Do-not-use-using-for-WCF-Clients)) where you call the service in a try/catch (making sure you close or abort). (which works well in a stateless application)

looking into Silverlight, where do we apply the abort/close pattern? as the service call is async and the application is state full.

At the moment the only thing I can think of is some sort of dynamic proxy (using something like Castle DP) accompanied with the ChannelFactoryManager from the [n-tier app, about 1/2 way down the page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474212/Zombie-Explorer-A-N-Tier-application-from-top-to-b) example. where the proxy will ensure there is always an open channel and the ChannelFactoryManager will handle the faults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using Castle DP with the ChannelFactoryManager implemented and detailed here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502121/WCF-in-a-stateful-application-WPF-Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

Because of the asynchronous nature of the Silverlight networking environment I recommend you to build more testable ServiceAgents - long-living singleton wrappers around silverlight's client proxies with callbacks for service methods. You can check real-proxy state (& recreate if needed) before calling service methods or use channel Faulted event. For ex:

```
public void GetOptionsAsync(Action<GetOptionsCompletedEventArgs> callback)
{
    try
    {
        CheckProxy();

        EventHandler<GetOptionsCompletedEventArgs> handler = null;

        handler = (sender, args) =>
        {
           Proxy.GetOptionsCompleted -= handler;
           if (args.Error != null)
           {
               //...
           }
           if (callback != null)
           {
               callback(args);
           }
        };

        Proxy.GetOptionsCompleted += handler;

        Proxy.GetOptionsAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception unknownException)
    {
       //...
       throw;
    }
}

public override void ResetProxy() //AbortProxy/CloseProxy
{
    if (Proxy != null)
    {
        try
        {
            Proxy.CloseProxy(); //extension method to handle exception while closing
        }
        catch (Exception unknownException) //CommunicationObjectFaultedException
        {
            //...
            Proxy.Abort();
        }               
    }

    CreateProxy();          
}

public override void CheckProxy()
{
    if (Proxy == null || (Proxy.State != CommunicationState.Opened && Proxy.State != CommunicationState.Created))
    {               
        ResetProxy();
    }
}

public override void CreateProxy() //RecreateProxy
{           
     Proxy = new WcfClient();

     Proxy.InnerChannel.Faulted += OnChannelFaulted;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input - sounds close to proxy suggestion in the question. How does your solution work, what does it inherit, can the consumer work directly with the service interface and does the developer need to develop a wrapper for each service?